# How do I Merge this feature/react-intl branch with Git?

Tags: git, reactjs, github, react-redux

I want to merge this feature/react-intl branch with git as described here => https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/react-intl/docs/recipes/how-to-integrate-react-intl.md

I started by cloning the latest version of the React Starter Kit (RSK) as described here => https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/feature/redux/docs/getting-started.md

```
$ git clone -o react-starter-kit -b master --single-branch \
  https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit.git MyApp
$ cd MyApp
```

The first step of How To Integrate React Intl says to 
"merge feature/react-intl branch with git"

How do I accomplish this?

I've attempted

```
git merge --no-ff feature/react-intl
```

response:

```
merge: feature/react-intl - not something we can merge.
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I've created an issue for clarifying the docs. https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1939

Answer (score 1):

Pull `feature/react-intl` branch since you have only *origin/master* branch locally ( cause of using **--single-branch** flag when cloned).

```
$ git remote -v
# i guess your remote name is 'react-starter-kit' instead 'origin'

$ git pull react-starter-kit feature/react-intl
```

OR, fetch remote *react-starter-kit* then merge `feature/react-intl` with local branch `master`.

```
$ git fetch react-starter-kit
$ git merge feature/react-intl
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume the first suggestion is supposed to happen after the `git clone` in the OP, and not instead of it? I got a tonneo' merge conflicts, presumably because of https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1871

After trying the second suggestion, I got the same error as in the OP.